# Summing entries in R based on perfect matches?

Tags: r, matching

I have an excel spreadsheet where some researchers caught fish, and then recorded each entry as one catch of fish. Because of this, a lot of information is duplicated. I would like to use some entry matching in R to change the way the spreadsheet looks, but I'm not sure how?

For instance, right now my spreadsheet looks like:

```
Year  Location  TimeStarted  TimeEnded  Species
1974  H11       11:00 AM     12:30 PM   Black Rockfish
1974  H11       11:00 AM     12:30 PM   Black Rockfish
1974  H11       11:00 AM     12:30 PM   Black Rockfish
1974  H11       2:00 AM      3:30 AM    Copper Rockfish
1974  N80       11:00 AM     1:20 PM    Copper Rockfish
```

And I would like to look like:

```
Year  Location  TimeStarted  TimeEnded  Black RF  Copper RF
1974  H11       11:00 AM     12:30 PM   3         0
1974  H11       2:00 AM      3:30 AM    0         1
1974  N80       11:00 AM     1:20 PM    0         1
```

So in essence, I need 1.) entries to match perfectly and then if they do, 2.) have R sum the number of species for perfectly matching entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df` is the dataset, you could try:

```
 library(reshape2)
 dcast(df, ...~Species, value.var="Species", length)
 #     Year Location TimeStarted TimeEnded Black Rockfish Copper Rockfish
 #1 1974      H11    11:00 AM  12:30 PM              3               0
 #2 1974      H11     2:00 AM   3:30 AM              0               1
 #3 1974      N80    11:00 AM   1:20 PM              0               1
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
  df%>%
  group_by(Year, Location, TimeStarted, TimeEnded, Species)%>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(Species, n, fill=0)
  #  Year Location TimeStarted TimeEnded Black Rockfish Copper Rockfish
  #1 1974      H11    11:00 AM  12:30 PM              3               0
  #2 1974      H11     2:00 AM   3:30 AM              0               1
  #3 1974      N80    11:00 AM   1:20 PM              0               1
```

Comment: I just tried this on a tiny part of the data set - worked perfectly! Glad I asked instead of banging my head against the wall more; I hadn't heard of the reshape2 package. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the formula method of `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(Species ~ ., dat, summary)
#   Year Location TimeStarted TimeEnded Species.BlackRockfish Species.CopperRockfish
# 1 1974      N80     11:00AM    1:20PM                     0                      1
# 2 1974      H11     11:00AM   12:30PM                     3                      0
# 3 1974      H11      2:00AM    3:30AM                     0                      1
```

where `dat` is

```
dat <- 
structure(list(Year = c(1974L, 1974L, 1974L, 1974L, 1974L), Location = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("H11", "N80"), class = "factor"), 
    TimeStarted = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("11:00 AM", 
    "2:00 AM"), class = "factor"), TimeEnded = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1:20 PM", "12:30 PM", "3:30 AM"
    ), class = "factor"), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Black Rockfish", "Copper Rockfish"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Year", 
"Location", "TimeStarted", "TimeEnded", "Species"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: This is a particularly elegant way of doing it - thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Except for the column names... :-)

Comment: $Richard Scriven.  I get a different output using the same code.  For example, I get `Species.Length, Species.Class, Species.Mode`, the last two gives `character` entries.  I am using `R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)` in linux.  I would assume it as new feature in `R 3.1.1`

Comment: @akrun - it might be because I removed the spaces within column variables before I read the data in.  i.e. one row is `1974      H11     11:00AM   12:30PM  BlackRockfish`

Comment: @Richard Scriven. Thanks for the reply.  I tried using `str_trim`.  but still not getting it correct.

Comment: @akrun -  I added the data I used to my answer.  I still get the same results every time.

Comment: @Richard Scriven.  Thanks.  Now, I understand the problem.  I used `character` columns instead of `factor` class.  Now, it works.